# MySQL PHP: Can't get any results

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to just print the content of my MySQL Database with PHP.

This is how my database looks like:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_myTable |
+-------------------+
| users             |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+
| Nick       |
+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
    <?php
echo "HI"; //to see, that the php gets runned at all.

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('myTable');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td></tr>"; 
}

echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

But on the website, the only output I get is

```
"HI"
```

I checked the username, passwd and DB-Names in my PHP.

I'm running an apache2 Server on Ubuntu (Ubuntu Gnome, if that matters) 16.10 and the community version of MySQL

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard is there a way to do it without? I am a beginner in PHP/SQL and would like to have an easy fix (just for learning, I could learn PDO's after learning the bases).

Comment: @JayBlanchard TY :) Appearently theres an error with connect...

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/genmainpage.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(26): include() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/genmainpage.php on line 6

Comment: I can not see any direct problems with your code. One possibility is that you are running PHP7, which does not include the mysql-lib. Unless you have proper error logging it may kill you script after the initial output.

Comment: No - you should learn properly right out of the gate. And the error you're getting is why. The The `mysql_*` API is not available on your system, so switching now is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I used mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) selects a `database`, yet you pass your table name as a parameter. Table name is different from database name. Check your database name using

```
show databases;
```

and use that instead of table name on `mysql_select_db`

Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you need to use `mysqli_*` functions or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

It is also a bad idea to run queries like

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

it is better to select the columns you need explicitly, like

```
SELECT name FROM users
```

EDIT

I was confused by the database name, which seems to be myTable indeed. The problem was that the deprecated functions were not found.

Comment: It looks like their database is called `myTable`

Comment: Ok, after using mysqli everything worked. The problem weren't the databases, as I got a little bit caught while fastly changing the names for the stackoverflow post (The names weren't adult enough for such a cool forum ;'))

Comment: @Andy thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThefrenchSpeedruns you are right, the problem was that the deprecated functions were not found on your end. I have edited my answer accordingly. If the answer helped you solve your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad I had to wait two minutes ;(

Answer (score 2):

Given your error message `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` it may look like you have a version of PHP that lacks the `mysql_` library.

The `mysql_` library was removed in 7.x, [and there are many reasons for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). You either have to rewrite your code using mysqli or PDO, OR downgrade your PHP version to 5.x (although I would strongly advice against this).

Comment: yeah, I checked version, I'm on 7.0 so, I used mysqli